# Reasons to Stay with Safari Browser

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome

I know many Mac OS X users would prefer to use Google Chrome, I so hope that I could do so but here are my reasons why I stick with Safari:

1. I could play Facebook video using HTML5 player with a simple plugin, I found none of the same in Google Chrome
2. Safari browser can integrate with Mac OS X social network accounts for one-click share to Facebook, Twitter, Email etc...
3. It seems to me that Safari is more energy efficient especially on Mavericks compare to Google Chrome.

If you have better suggestions that I could resolve the above and switch to Google Chrome, please feedback. Constructive comments are most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you "trying" to switch to Chrome? If you like Safari... stick with Safari...

- Marginally better JavaScript performance (according to the SunSpider benchmark)
- iCloud tabs
- App Nap
- More customizable interface
- Reading list

Whereas Chrome offers a different set of extensions, and tab syncing via its own cloud service (which also requires Chrome on all your devices).

Personally, ClickToFlash is the deal breaker for me, until Chrome let's me load piss-poor Flash videos in a QuickTime plugin, I'm saying away from it

Comment: Totally agree with you... ClickToFlash is deal breaker!